# Populate {% csrf_token %} when using render_to_string?

Tags: python, django

I need to use render_to_string, but I can't use

```
@csrf_protect
```

and pass

```
context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

to render_to_string because I think that the decorator is expecting an HttpResponse, not a SafeString.

How can I get the csrf_token into the form in my string?

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'COOKIES'

Edit: Thanks for the comments, here's some clarification:

I am creating a 'panel' system, similar to 'portlets', where panels are configured in the database (including the name of the python function to render the panel as a string - the panel functions are imported at runtime from their names in the database).

In order to put these panels into pages, I have created a custom template tag, which reads the names of the needed panels from the DB, renders them a strings, then returns one big blob of html (as a string) to the page being rendered.  (This allows users to choose which panles are displayed for them.)

My problem is that one of the panels (simple python functions which use render_to_string to render a template as a string) has a form in it.

I need to insert the CSRF field into that form, as it is being rendered as a string.

Comment: I cannot visualize what you're doing. Show code.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you described the problem you have not the solution you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've worked around the problem, but I'd still really like a good solution.

The panel function now looks like:

```
def render_to_s(request, *args, **kwargs):
    panelDisplays = PanelDisplay.listAll()
    csrf_token_value = request.COOKIES['csrftoken']

    c = {"panelDisplays": panelDisplays, "csrf_token_value": csrf_token_value}
    return render_to_string('panels/config.html', c)
```

While the template now includes:

```
<div style='display:none'><input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='{{ csrf_token_value }}'/></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your view you use request.COOKIES['csrftoken']
I'm not sure if the cookie is always available, so my solution is to generate the csrf token on each request.

```
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token

def render_to_s(request, *args, **kwargs):
    panelDisplays = PanelDisplay.listAll()
    csrf_token_value = get_token(self.request)

    c = {"panelDisplays": panelDisplays, "csrf_token_value": csrf_token_value}
    return render_to_string('panels/config.html', c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Views should always return HttpResponse (or one of it's ancestors). So you should return `HttpResponse(your_rendered_string)`, but it's the same as calling `render_to_response`. If you need to modify response body, you can do it with response too:

```
response = render_to_response(...)
response.content = response.content.replace('A', 'B')
return response
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about views, I am using render_to_string, called from within a custom template tag, hence the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a complete solution.  All derived from this excellent post.

This is based on a scenario where you want to include an invitation form on several pages of your site, without repeating yourself.

invitations.widgets.py:

```
from invitations.forms import InvitationForm
from django.middleware.csrf import get_token
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def invitation_widget_function (request):
    # ... blah blah blah 
    # ... stuff I don't want 
    # ... to repeat in every view
    invitation_form = InvitationForm ()
    csrf_token_value = get_token(request)
    context = { 'invitation_form': invitation_form, 
                'csrf_token_value': csrf_token_value }
    return render_to_string ( 'invitation_widget_template.html', context )
```

invitation_widget_template.html:

```
<form action="/whatever/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}  {# don't do this because it won't work in streamed output #}
    {# do this instead: #}
    <div style='display:none'>
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken value='{{ csrf_token_value }}'/>
    </div>
    {{ invitation_form }}
    <button type="submit">Invite Someone</button>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
from invitations.widgets import invitation_widget_function 
from django.shortcuts import render         

def page_view (request):
    invitation_widget = invitation_widget_function(request)
    context = { 'invitation_widget': invitation_widget }
    return render (request, 'page_template.html', context )
```

page_template.html:

```
<body>
    <div>
    {% include "some_normal_template.html" %} {# takes context from page_view() #}

    {{ invitation_widget }} {# not an include, but a fully rendered string #}
    {# took context from invitation_widget_function() -- has csrf token included #}
    </div>
</body>
```